# Interrupt in 8085 microprocessor

Tags: microprocessor, 8085

What's the mechanism whereby the external device places a RST instruction on the bus, along with an interrupt # 0-7? I only know that external device sends signal to INTR pin to interrupt 8085

Answer (score 2):

When an interrupt comes in on the INTR line, the 8085 makes the \$\small \overline{\text{INTA}}\$ line low for two cycles.  This is typically used to enable a tri-state buffer like the 74LS244, so a RST instruction can be placed on the data bus.

The input of the buffer is either hardwired to generate a specific RST instruction (if there is only one such interrupt in the system, e.g. RST 5 would be 0xEF), or more typically wired to a priority encoder (such as a 74LS148) that outputs a number 0-7 on its three output lines which in turn are used to generate a unique RST for each interrupt.

[image]

The opcode of a RST instruction is encoded as:

```
       1   1   I5  I4  I3   1   1   1
```

where the 1's correspond to the lines hardwired to +5V above, and I5 I4 I3 correspond to the three lines from the encoder.

Note when I5, I4, and I3 = 5, the same instruction 0xEF is generated as before.

Its also possible to put a CALL instruction on the bus, but that takes multiple cycles.

Answer (score 1):

The same mechanism that any other memory or peripheral uses: when the CPU asks for it, it puts its 8-bit code on the data bus. In this case it is the interrupt acknowledge that signals the read as reading the interrupt vector istruction.